# Using ng2-translate pipe or directive for placeholder

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I would like to use ng2-translate for placeholder. Only way to do this I found is use ng2-translate service and pass variable to placeholder like this:

```
class Form {
  placeholder: string;

  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.get('placeholder.value').subscribe(
      (placeholder: string) => this.placeholder = placeholder,
    );
  }
}

<input type="email" placeholder={{placeholder}}/>
```

But it looks bulky. Is there way to use ng2-translate for placeholder with pipe or directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive), If your language json file is a below

```
{
  "placeholder": {
    "value" : "Your placeholder text"
  }
}
```

then you can use `translate` `pipe` as below :

```
<input type="email" [placeholder]="'placeholder.value' | translate" />
```

Comment: For me, this case works with text (div, span etc.), but with input it renders not input control but text: <input type="email" placeholder=Your placeholder text />

Comment: may be `<input type="email" [placeholder]="'placeholder.value' | translate" />`  will work, check it .